# printf cause problems with output

Tags: c, string

I have a little problem with the following C code. If I comment out "**LINE 24**" then I'll get the following output:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
and if I don't comment it, I'll get the following:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadƔ?LƔ?LƔF?W?F?W?F?W?F?W?F?W?F?W?F?W?

Can somebody tell me why?
*I am using mac os x 10.5.4 and gcc*

```
void test(char* a , char* b);

int main()
{
    char * str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    char* str2 = malloc(4*sizeof(str));
    test(str , str2);
    return 0;
}

void test(char* a , char* b)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("\n########\n");
    for( i = 0 ; i < strlen(a)  ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d" , i);   /******** LINE 24 ********/ 
        b[i] = a[i];        
    }

    printf("\n########\n");
    for( i = 0 ; i < strlen(b) ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c" ,*(b+i));
    }
    printf("\n########\n");

}
```

Thank you for responding.

Comment: What do you think `strlen(b)` should return if you are not feeding it a 0-terminated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

First the allocation of `str2`:

```
 char* str2 = malloc(4*sizeof(str));  // This will allocate 4 times the size of a char pointer. You cannot be sure that str will fit!
```

Second the copying of `a` to `b`.
You need to add a string terminator at the end of `b`:

```
for( i = 0 ; i < strlen(a)  ; i++)
{
    printf("%d" , i);   /******** LINE 24 ********/ 
    b[i] = a[i];        
}
b[i] = '\0';   // Make sure b is properly terminated
```

Comment: Also he calls strlen on every iteration, which is undesirable in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
char* str2 = malloc(4*sizeof(str));
```

`str` is a pointer which size is (presumably) 32 bit -> 4 bytes. So what you are allocating is not the size of the string, but the size four pointers to a string would require (16 bytes), whilke your string is 26 bytes long (including the `0` byte).

Addirtionally, when you output a string you must allocate one byte more than the length, to account for the `0` byte which indicates the end of the string.

```
char * str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
char* str2 = malloc(strlen(str)+1);

int i;
for( i = 0 ; i < strlen(a)  ; i++)
{
    printf("%d" , i);   /******** LINE 24 ********/ 
    b[i] = a[i];        
}
b[i] = 0; // Terminate the string.
```

If you don't terminate the string, then functions working on strings (like `strlen`, `printf` etc.) will scan the string untl they encounter the `0` byte which can be anywhere in your memory. So the `strlen` in your code, can sometimes seem to give the correct length if such a byte happens to be right at the end, but it will give wrong results more often (undefined behaviour), which accounts for the strange chars you see at your output.